# Spring cloud stream @InboundChannelAdapter not working

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to get the easiest spring cloud stream example to work, so I decided to implement the one from the reference guide [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_getting_started).
I want it to work with kafka so I made too application both with

> spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka

as a dependency. I also tried with rabbitMq by replacint it with

> spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit

I can't get it to work however. I don't get any exceptions and i can see that the source puts works, the sink however isn't printing the message. I am sure that it connects correctly to kafka/rabbitMq, because i don't get any exceptions and if i don't run kafka/rabbitMq I do get exceptions. I am also using the destination parameter when i run the apps (like it says in the guide), so it should be using the same destination.

I am using spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE and spring cloud Camden.SR2

Anyone know what i missed?

Comment: Hi, Do you see the messages in the configured destinations topic/exchange in Kafka/Rabbit when the source sends the messages? Also, how do you set the destination names for the output/input bindings?

Comment: I set the destination names like they say in the guide, so by supplying --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=mydest for the source and the input one for the sink

Comment: ok, when you said ` i can see that the source puts works`  - does this mean you can see the source output messages at topic/exchange at Kafka/Rabbit?

Comment: Haven't changed anything but now it works in rabbit. Must haven't been thinking straight yesterday. It still doesn't work with kafka. My impression was that i could just switch those dependencies to choose between kafka and rabbit.

Comment: Can you share the two applications you are using? This should really work out of the box - for comparison try the `source` and `sink` projects from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/ - using the Kafka binder instead of Rabbit.